# Is it proper English to say "allocate [someone] among [something]"

Tags: vocabulary

Searching on the Internet one can find plenty of sentences where "allocate [something] among [someone]" appears, for instance (Google Books):

- The Congress amended the law to require OPOs "to **allocate donated organs equitably among transplant patients** according to established medical criteria."
- It becomes effective if and when norms and categories for the distribution of insufficient capacities have to be established in order to **allocate scarce resources among several needy persons** through competition.

But, if one tries finding a fragment like "allocate [someone] among [something]" the search results begin more scattered, almost like it is not proper or idiomatic English to use "allocate" that way. An example of this kind is (Google Books):

- If the solution to a problem can only be expressed in whole numbers, as would be the case if the problem involved how to **allocate people among various tasks or departments**, then linear programming models can't be used.

So, is it proper English to say  "allocate [someone] among [something]"?

Comment: I don't think one would use *among*. But "allocate people to houses" would work: you are sending individuals in different directions (which is why *to* is appropriate).

Comment: @Andrew, how about "You can also choose how to allocate the new citizens among the five racial categories," which I found on The New York Times as a rare example of this usage?

Comment: But, @Andrew, after some thoughts, it arose a doubt to me, differently from "to", don't "among" in your example give a better sense of "division". I.e., a person is placed in a house, three persons are placed in another house, and so on? So the persons involved are separated, read divided, in a certain  number of houses, no?

Comment: Personally, I think it's a rather clunky way of saying what would perhaps be better expressed using *pigeonhole, categorise*, or *assign*, etc., depending on the exact sense and nuance intended.

Comment: Could you post any examples where "people" (and not the singular, person) are *allocated among* "things"? And where "things" are *allocated among* a person or people?

Comment: @Mari, I have difficult to think one of the first kind, but "allocate tasks among people" can work if the "tasks" are considered "things".

Comment: Yes, that's a good example. But I was referring to your research on the Internet. What did you find exactly? Especially the "snippets". I just think your question would be clearer if there were examples, that's all.

Comment: @Mari, I added some example and reworded the question hoping it is more clear now.

Comment: Your examples all show plural objects being allocated, so "[someone]" (singular) in the question is not indicated.

Comment: @AndrewLeach That's why the OP is asking the question! He wants to know why the reverse can't be true (that's how I interpret his question).

Comment: @AndrewLeach In theory, could a homeless person be "allocated" to a home OR "among" several different homes? *I think* that's what Carlo's asking.

Answer (score 1):

It makes little sense to allocate a singular person ("We allocated Ted among the houses on the block"), as you'd be separating Ted into parts and putting each part in a house. However it does make sense to say "We allocated all the people among the houses on the block". As Andrew said, the usage of the word "among" is awkward, but it's still correct.

Comment: So, you are saying that "among" used there is correct but is not idiomatic English? Or, maybe, is that "not idiomatic" and "awkward" mean different things?

Comment: "not idiomatic" and "awkward" certainly have *different* meanings.

Comment: @Carlo: A person can certainly be *allocated something* (he gets the thing), or *allocated **to** something* (he becomes "subservient" to the thing). You could perhaps ***allocate** a camp-follower prostitute **among** a company of soldiers* (some or all of those soldiers might [get some action](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/action)). But generally speaking, people aren't divided up into bits and allocated/shared around **among** anything.

Comment: @Carlo_R. In my opinion, it's both; however, people's opinions of what is awkward may vary.